# Is it possible to add pages dynamically when using WiX

Tags: wix

I am currently evaluating installer technology.  One of the main tasks I need to complete is to be able to take a number from a user and to repeat a set of pages that number of times.

I can see how to add a new page into WiX but is there anyway to dynamically show pages according to user input - this is not a choice of one flow or another.

Thanks

Comment: is there a maximum the number can become? And I assume you not only want do display the set of pages, but also process the user input of each page displayed?

Answer (score 1):

As Wimmel suggested you may want to put a maximum number of dialogs in your installer but then display only some of them depending on user input. If that's not a viable option then maybe you can use external UI handler and write the whole GUI in language of choice. (Hint: I have written a tool called SharpSetup that simplifies the job for C#.)

Comment: Thank you for confirming.  Theoretically there is no maximum but realistically there are limits that could be applied.  I want to avoid writing code if at all possible with the hope that it will aid maintainability (I know there are pros and cons to this).  NSIS also can't do this but in the same manner you can put pages in and turn them off.